# Inject a constant before loading constructor

Tags: angularjs

I need a constant to be ready before controllers are loaded. Here's what I tried (lamely) :-

```
    $stateProvider.state("landing", {
            templateUrl : "/landing/landingTemplate.html",
            url : "/landing",
            controller : "landingController",
            resolve : {
                returnState = function getReady() {
                    $http.get("data/Config.json").then(function(response) {
                        callGuiConfig = response.data;
                        callApp.constant('callGuiConfig', callGuiConfig);
                        return "ready";
                    });
                }
            }
```

But I got this error :-

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

in line : `returnState = function getReady() {`

Am I using resolver the wrong way?

Comment: resolve is an object, so write it as: `returnState : function getReady() {`, additionally, inject anything that will be needed inside that function: `getReady($http)` (additionally x2: return the Promise - `return $http.get(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

This is the official way to handle constants.

```
angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('MOVIE_TITLE', 'The Matrix');

.controller('MyController', function (MOVIE_TITLE) {
  expect(MOVIE_TITLE).toEqual('The Matrix');
});
```

You will be interested in second row here, rest is just for the sake of example.
Note here, constant can object, array etc. Not only a string.

Characteristics of constants made this way are:
it is a singleton it is not Instantiable and it is not Configurable

If you need something that decorators can manage and change you need `.value()`

For more info on that and other providers:
https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider.state("landing", {
    templateUrl : "/landing/landingTemplate.html",
    url : "/landing",
    controller : "landingController",
    resolve : {
        returnState : ['$http','callApp', function($http, callApp) {
            return $http.get("data/Config.json").then(function(response) {
                var callGuiConfig = response.data;
                //what is callApp??
                callApp.constant('callGuiConfig', callGuiConfig);
                return "ready";
            });
        }]
    }
};
```

What is callApp? I'm assuming its a service that sets/gets constants. If not then remove it from injected parameters.